# Selecting specific channel entries, to link to a given entry

Tags: ee3, how-to

I have been using Playa to choose from my existing entries, to create a list of related entries/similar entries. I use the following fields in the linking:

- title
- url
- image (a custom channel field that I create, that is used in each entry)

Playa is not being ported to EE3, so I have to learn a new way/find a new plugin that lets me do this. Since I choose the related entries, and there are other entries that will have the same tags, I cannot use EE's native Relationships functionality/tag without significantly changing/re-learning how I organize my site and tag my content. (The level of tagging needed to relate the entries would be...untenable, to say the least.)

Does EE3.x have a way for me to select entries from the current channel to be linked on a given entry, and have those entries' title, url, and image fields available to me to use in linking?

Comment: I dont understand.. why not to use in built relationships fieldtype ?

Comment: Because to create the linking I want to do, the tagging would get WAY too granular, WAY to fast. I have (for example) an entry about one particular cool purple eyeshadow with a shimmer finish. I want to link to its parent-collection (Relationships can do that) and to other, similar-looking, cool purple eyeshadows with shimmer finishes from other vendors. But there are LOTS of other entries tagged with 'cool', 'purple', 'eyeshadow', and 'shimmer' that are darker, lighter, warmer...and I don't want to link to those entries from this entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple answer to your specific question is yes - the [relationships field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/relationships.html) does exactly what you describe.  The relationships field is very similar in function to Playa, and indeed Ellis Labs have written a very handy [migration tool](https://github.com/EllisLab/PlayaMatrixImporter) that will automatically convert your existing EE2 Playa (and Matrix) fields to EE2/3 Relationship / Grid fields.